# How to measure size (KB) of text object stored in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I am using Django 1.8 with [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) to store a json object in my PostgreSQL database (v9.2).

Can I calculate the size of the json object (which is actually a text field) in KB or MB before or after storing it?

The reason I ask is because I 've read somewhere that there is a limit of the size of the text field. So, I might need to compress it before storing it.

Comment: *the longest possible character string that can be stored is about* [1 GB](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) -- I would say, you don't have to worry much, unless you store contents of massive books, or images in base64. But in these cases, you should use [LOB](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html)s anyways.

Comment: `octet_length` and `pg_column_size` are what you want.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how to use them in an answer so I can accept it?